# formula to count multiple occurences of char and and multiply with corresponding value from list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a list of people which order menu's from a list each day. In the end I want a weekly sum for every person.

The problem here is, that every person can order more than one menu per day.

My current formula to count all occurrences of one menu is

```
{=SUM(LEN(B$2:F$2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B$2:F$2,$A$6,"")))}
```

Then I build a sum formula in an extra column for every day that consists of this formula multiplied with its corresponding price added for every menu item. This leads to this pretty ugly formula even for Monday in `G2`:

```
{=SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$6,"")))*$B$6+SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$7,"")))*$B$7+SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$8,"")))*$B$8+SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$9,"")))*$B$9+SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$10,"")))*$B$10+SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$11,"")))*$B$11+SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$12,"")))*$B$12+SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$13,"")))*$B$13+SUM(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,$A$14,"")))*$B$14}
```

Can anyone think of a better formula:

1. to count multiple occurrences over multiple cells
2. to calculate the sum for the whole week without extra columns

[image]

**ARRAY-FORMULAS: CTRL + SHIFT +ENTER**

Comment: What cells contain each of those formulas and is the screenshot the desired result?

Comment: the first formula is part of the second formula. the second formula is in cell `G2` and can be copied till `L3`. Y>ou can copy formula 1 everywhere to get the number of x's for person 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a `CSE` formula here.

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(B2:F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:F2,A$6:A$14,"")))*B$6:B$14)`

returns 19.75, though using only a single formula.

Copy down as required.

Regards

Comment: Beautiful, i knew something like this was out there, but i couldnt get in touch with it. Just some nitpicking though, `SUMPRODUCT` in itself is an array formula. Would have really wondered if it worked without it. Awesome work, thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Re array formulas, it depends upon your definition. SUMPRODUCT does not require CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, though it does behave as an array formula.